# How to override wordpress native options with theme options

Tags: theme-development

In `wp-admin/options-reading.php` there are options such as `posts_per_page`. How do I override it with my theme options page form?

I tried adding a text field with the option name but it didn't work: `<input type="text" name="posts_per_page" />`.

Comment: A option is a option because its value can be choosen by the user. From my point of view, forcing specific settings through the theme is a very bad approach.

Comment: I just want it in my theme options. How can I do that?

Comment: @Ahmed, I deleted my answer because it was completely wrong! I didn't read the question correctly, sorry for that.